# I am trying to run this program but it gives error initwindow() not initialized

Tags: c++, c, graphics, bgi

The code basically implements B-MFR Routing protocol.  It is probably a trivial error but I can't resolve it.

```
#include <graphics.h>
        #include<conio.h>
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include<math.h>
        #include<string.h>
        #include<time.h>
        #define RADI 125
        
        int points[100][2];
        int dist[25][25];
        int k;
        int path[25];
        
        int distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
        {
              return (int)sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2)+pow(y1-y2,2));
        }
        
        
        void printscreen()
        {
             char str[5];
             //cleardevice();
             for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                     circle(points[i][0],points[i][1],3);
                     itoa(i+1,str,10);
                     outtextxy(points[i][0]+3,points[i][1]+3,str);
            }
        }
        void drawgraphics(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2, int rad)
        {
             int x=RADI;
             while(x!=rad)
             {
                          //printscreen();
                          setcolor(15);
                          circle(x1,y1,x);
                          printscreen();
                          delay(15);
                          setcolor(0);
                          setfillstyle(EMPTY_FILL ,0);
                          circle(x1,y1,x);
                          x--;
             }
                   setcolor(15);
                   printscreen();
                   line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                   //circle(x1,y1,rad);
                   delay(100);
        }
        void getpath(int start,int end,int rad)
        {
             int flag,current=start,min,prev;
             path[0]=start+1;
             k=1;
             while (current!=end)
             {
                   rad=RADI;
                   flag=1;
                   prev=current;
                   while (flag)
                   {
                         min=1000;
                         for (int i=0;i<25;i++)
                         {
                             if (rad==dist[current][i]&&dist[current][end]>dist[i][end])
                             {
                                flag=0;
        
                                if (min>dist[i][end])
                                {
                                   min=dist[i][end];
                                   current=i;
                                }
                             }
                         }
                         rad--;
                         if(rad<0)
                         {
                                  printf("\nNo Node found in Radius.\n");
                                  return;
                         }
                   }
                   path[k]=current+1;
                   drawgraphics(points[prev][0],points[prev][1],points[current][0],points[current][1],rad+1);
                   k++;
             }
        }
        int main()
        {
            initwindow(640,480,"B-MFR Routing Protocol");
            srand (time(NULL));
        
            for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                     points[i][0]= rand() % 550 + 50;
                     points[i][1]= rand() % 400 + 50;
            }
            printscreen();
        
            for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                    for(int j=0; j<25; j++)
                    {
                            dist[i][j]=distance(points[i][0],points[i][1],points[j][0],points[j][1]);
                    }
            }
        
            int start,end;
            printf("Enter start:");
            scanf("%d",&start);
            printf("Enter end:");
            scanf("%d",&end);
            start--;
            end--;
        
            getpath(start,end,RADI);
            printf("\n");
            printf("%d ",path[0]);
            for(int i=1;i<k;i++)
            {
                    printf("%d ",path[i]);
                    line(points[path[i-1]-1][0],points[path[i-1]-1][1],points[path[i]-1][0],points[path[i]-1][1]);
            }
            getche();
        }
```

Comment: Is the error when compiling or when running? Can you also please add the exact text of the error message?

Comment: error while compiling "Function initwindow should have a prototype"

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: This page (http://onecore.net/turbo-c-graphics-programming.htm) says you need to use initgraph - initwindow seems to be for winbgim. I am not sure - haven't used Turbo C for 20 years. Possibly you need to install winbgim.

Answer (score 1):

**The Dark** Certainly appears to be on the right track. None of the [openbgi header files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openbgi/) mention initwindow.
There *is* an `initgraph`

```
void initgraph(int   *graphdriver, int   *graphmode, const char  *pathtodriver);
```

I did find a fairly [ancient reference to BGI](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/source/) which has a graphics.h that contains the initwindow declaration that appears to be missing.

Without knowing precisely which collection of 3rd party code the OP is using it is hard to say what's really going on here.

Comment: i have added initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC4\\TC\\BGI"),still same error

Comment: The error "Function ... should have a prototype" means you need to declare the function as I've given you, in a header file, but preferably that header file should already exist in the library you're using. If it is not and you aren't giving us enough information to go on here, then it's really hard to determine which function you _should_ be using instead.